# An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in SConnect.exe but was not handled in user code

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to develop an app in WP8.1. I am getting this error. I can't understand this:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   SConnect.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Getting here:

```
objXmppclient = new XMPPClient();

 public XMPPClient Get_XMPPConnection(string useid, string pswd)
{
       if (objXmppclient == null)
       {

        objXmppclient = new XMPPClient();-------------here getting error
        objXmppclient.JID = useid + "@taurus";

        objXmppclient.Password = pswd;
        objXmppclient.Server = ServerIPAddress;
        //objXmppclient.Port = 9090;
        objXmppclient.AutoReconnect = true;
        objXmppclient.RetrieveRoster = true;
        objXmppclient.AutoAcceptPresenceSubscribe = true;
        objXmppclient.AttemptReconnectOnBadPing = true;
        objXmppclient.AutoAcceptPresenceSubscribe = true;
        objXmppclient.Connect();
    }
    return objXmppclient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your XMPPClient object needs the System.Windows Assembly in the version 2.0.5.0 which isn't available on your testing system.

That is the case because the System.Windows referenced in the XMPPClient is from the .Net Framework 2.0 which isn't installed on a 8/8.1 system.

You either have to get that Version (and it's dependencies) onto your phone (don't know if Phone 8.1 is compatible to Framework 2.0) or you have to use a different XMPP client that does reference a newer version of the Framework that is installed on your Phone 8.1.

Comment: i am using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.this code works fine in 8.0 but not in 8.1

Comment: The exception you get is the Framework trying to load the Assembly System.Windows in the version 2.0.5.0 which is part of the .Net Framework 2.0. My guess is, that in 8.1 the Framework got removed entirely and so the DLL can no longer be found. Don't have a phone 8.1 around though to test it.

Comment: If possible install Framework 2.0 (that would be the cleanest and fastest version). If not, you could try copying the respecitve DLLs with your application (that would be the quick and dirty approach that might fail hard actually) or you get a XMPP client that uses a newer Framework. If you got the sources for the XMPP client, you can do that yourself, it is just time consuming.

Comment: i searched google but i didint get xmppclient source code for windows.Then how can i?

Comment: If it is a closed source library, you can't. Even if it isn't you'd need to look at the license. All you can try then is ask the developer of the XMPPclient.